# Create tables in a loop with appropriate names

Tags: function, loops, plpgsql

I want to create tables for a number of years.
The basic structure of my query is something like:

```
    drop table if exists stock;
create table stock as
select distinct t1.id, t2.id_, t2.year
from mytable t1
join mytable_ t2 on t1.person = t2.person
where t2.year = y_current;
```

with y_current>=1980 and <=2015.

My idea is to use a function in order to loop over years, but I don't know how to adapt the table name in a loop. Ideally, the code would create tables
stock_1980, stock_1981, ...., stock_2005, i.e. create tables with the year included.
I am sorry for asking this, I am from a different field with other languages where this kind of operation works!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION main(IN y_current INT) RETURNS VOID AS $$
DECLARE y_current INT;
BEGIN
y_current := 1980;
WHILE y_current < 2015 + 1 LOOP

drop table if exists stock_y_current;
create table stock_y_current as
select distinct t1.id, t2.id_, t2.year
from mytable t1
join mytable_ t2 on t1.person = t2.person
where t2.year = y_current;
where t1.earliest_filing_year = y_current;
y_current := y_current + 1;
END LOOP;
RETURN;
END;
$$ language 'plpgsql';
```

Comment: You need dynamic SQL for that. But why do you think you need that? A single table with a `year` column would be a better choice. Are you trying to implement [partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html)? There are better ways to do that.

Comment: Yes, I know that a single table would be better. But the table will get insanely big. I also want to create csv.files later for specific years and they are easier to handle by year. I will look at partitioning. Thanks for this hint.